# Unable to mount Azure ADLS Gen 2 on from Community Edition of Databricks : com.databricks.rpc.UnknownRemoteException: Remote exception occurred

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2, databricks-community-edition

I am trying to mount ADLS Gen 2 from my databricks Community Edition, but when I run the following code:

```
test = spark.read.csv("/mnt/lake/RAW/csds.csv", inferSchema=True, header=True)
```

I get the error:

```
com.databricks.rpc.UnknownRemoteException: Remote exception occurred:
```

I'm using the following code to mount ADLS Gen 2

```
def check(mntPoint):
  a= []
  for test in dbutils.fs.mounts():
    a.append(test.mountPoint)
  result = a.count(mntPoint)
  return result

mount = "/mnt/lake"

if check(mount)==1:
  resultMsg = "<div>%s is already mounted. </div>" % mount
else:
  dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "wasbs://root@axxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net",
  mount_point = mount,
  extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.xxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net":""})
  resultMsg = "<div>%s was mounted. </div>" % mount

displayHTML(resultMsg)


ServicePrincipalID = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
ServicePrincipalKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
DirectoryID =  'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
Lake =  'adlsgen2'


# Combine DirectoryID into full string
Directory = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{}/oauth2/token".format(DirectoryID)

# Create configurations for our connection
configs = {"fs.azure.account.auth.type": "OAuth",
           "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
           "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id": ServicePrincipalID,
           "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": ServicePrincipalKey,
           "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint": Directory}



mount = "/mnt/lake"

if check(mount)==1:
  resultMsg = "<div>%s is already mounted. </div>" % mount
else:
  dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = f"abfss://root@{Lake}.dfs.core.windows.net/",
  mount_point = mount,
  extra_configs = configs)
  resultMsg = "<div>%s was mounted. </div>" % mount
```

I then try to read a dataframe in ADLS Gen 2 using the following:

```
dataPath = "/mnt/lake/RAW/DummyEventData/Tools/"

test = spark.read.csv("/mnt/lake/RAW/csds.csv", inferSchema=True, header=True)

com.databricks.rpc.UnknownRemoteException: Remote exception occurred:
```

Any ideas?

Comment: please post the whole stacktrace

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt, do you mean
```/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)``

Comment: Or did you mean
```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3663922765211172> in <module>
----> 1 test = spark.read.csv("/mnt/lake/RAW/csds.csv", inferSchema=True, header=True)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in csv(self, path, schema, sep, encoding, quote, escape, comment, 
    762             path = [path]
    763         if type(path) == list:
--> 764             return self._df(self._jreader.csv(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
```

Comment: yes, include the error message from JVM - usually there should be a line, "Caused by"

Comment: I suspect that it could be caused by the security model of the community edition that is different from the "normal" Databricks

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt, that is what I was thinking. But I wanted to know for sure, before I started troubleshooting

Comment: @AlexOtt, just so you know, there isn't a line "Caused by"

Comment: Anyway it's hard to say without full stacktrace

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt, I'm not sure how to get you the full stracktrace? SO will only allow a certain number of characters

Comment: Put it into https://gist.github.com or something like and link it from post

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt, I have done this before with github, but here you https://gist.github.com/cpatte7372/f9a820e82c5e57befa919430b1b9af45
Let me know if you can access it?
Thanks

Comment: @AlexOtt, so I assigned the Service Principle with Storage Blob Data Contributor. Now, I'm able to read in the CSV using:
```test2 = spark.read.csv("abfss://root@adlspretbiukadlsdev.dfs.core.windows.net/RAW/csds.csv",inferSchema=True,header=True)```
But I'm  still getting the error when reading in the same CSV with:
```test = spark.read.csv("/mnt/lake/RAW/csds.csv", inferSchema=True, header=True)```

Comment: @AlexOtt, I re-added the code to https://gist.github.com/cpatte7372/f9a820e82c5e57befa919430b1b9af45 again just in case you have to check it out

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt, did you get a chance to take another look at the code?

Comment: I don’t know exactly, but I suspect something specific to community edition. I suggest just use full abfss url instead of mount - community edition isn’t the same as standard databricks

Comment: @AlexOtt thats what I thought. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the stacktrace, most probably reason for that error is that you don't have **Storage Blob Data Contributor** (or **Storage Blob Data Reader**) role assigned for your service principal (as it's described in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/adls-gen2/azure-datalake-gen2-sp-access#assign-roles)).  This role is different from usual "Contributor" role, and that's very confusing.